# Need help with if else statement

Tags: c#

I'm trying to do an else statement that would tell the user that the game ended in a draw (tic tac toe game). I got it where it works if played and there's a winner it will show another form declaring the winner through an if statement but I cant figure out the its a draw portion.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
namespace MyGame
{
    public class Result1
    {


        static private int[,] Winners = new int[,]
                   {
                       // main gameplay Ex: if x is on 0,1,2 x is the winner
                        {0,1,2},
                        {3,4,5},
                        {6,7,8},
                        {0,3,6},
                        {1,4,7},
                        {2,5,8},
                        {0,4,8},
                        {2,4,6},
                   };


        static public bool CheckWinner(Button[] myControls)
        {
            //bolean statement to check for the winner 
            bool gameOver = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                int a = Winners[i, 0];
                int b = Winners[i, 1];
                int c = Winners[i, 2];

                Button b1 = myControls[a], b2 = myControls[b], b3 = myControls[c];
                if (b1.Text == "" || b2.Text == "" || b3.Text == "")
                    continue;

                if (b1.Text == b2.Text && b2.Text == b3.Text)
                {

                    b1.BackColor = b2.BackColor = b3.BackColor = Color.LightCoral;
                    b1.Font = b2.Font = b3.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 32F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Italic & System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((System.Byte)(0)));
                    gameOver = true;
                    xWinnerForm xWinnerForm = new xWinnerForm();
                    xWinnerForm.ShowDialog(); //only works with show not showDialog method gets overloaded  (b1.Text + " is the Winner"); to get around this I added and image showing the last player


                }
                 //else statement here for draw what code would I put in?



            }


                   return gameOver;

        }



    }

}
```

Comment: Try reformatting your question please...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The game has ended in a draw when all spaces are filled and there is no winner.

Your check for this should not be in the `for` loop that is checking each winning line, but should a separate check, after that `for` loop. At that point, check to see if all the controls' `Text`s are non-blank, and if they are, you have a draw (if someone had won the previous code would have discovered that).